# SSRS Display One-To-Many Relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I have just begun using SSRS, and I was able to display records in a table page by page using a tablix.

The next step is to display a one to many relationship on the following page. For example, first page, customers data, second page, all notes for the given customer.

Sorry, I am sure this is a common question but I couldn't find any questions where the author had this exact goal, though I imagine this is a common and basic thing to do with SSRS

Using Joins seems to cause either duplicate customer data pages with one note per page or it causes the notes to appear after all customer data pages. So I'm guessing I'll have to use a second dataset somehow

Comment: Also should note I want to do this for each customer not for a given customer id parameter

Comment: You will need to post a sample of your data, even from the basic tables will be a start, and then a sketch of you expected output. This is probably simple to do but without more info it's just guesswork. Edit your question and provide more detail.

Comment: It is okay, I was able to achieve the desired end by using a sub report for each customer record with  page breaks

Comment: I think you are asking for a drill through report. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tutorial-creating-drillthrough-and-main-reports-report-builder?view=sql-server-2017